What are the different types of resonances in forced oscillation systems?
I'm currently studying resonances in systems subjected to forced oscillations and have come across various terms and cases that I'd like to understand more clearly. Specifically, I am analyzing a system where the forcing term has an excitation frequency $\Omega$ , and the system has natural frequencies $\omega_n$ for $n=1,2,...$
I am familiar with combination resonances of sum and difference types, defined as
$\Omega=\omega_n+\omega_m$ and $\Omega=\omega_n-\omega_m$ respectively. I also know about the principal parametric resonance where $\Omega=2\omega_n$.
However, I have questions about the basic case where $\Omega=\omega_n$. How is this type of resonance typically referred to?
Additionally, terms like primary resonance and secondary resonance are often mentioned. Can someone explain what these terms specifically refer to in the context of forced oscillation systems?
Any references would also be greatly appreciated since I found the literature on this terminology not very consistent or clear.

Related - Normal mode
